# Sufficient sampling size for logistical regression observational data

Tags: logistic, statistical-power, cluster-sample

As a part of my master thesis, I'm conducting an observational study of journalists' background and the effect of this on the approach to a certain case study. I have a fixed number of observations/articles, 781 to be precise. I know that some of them are likely written by the same journalists, but I don't know exactly how many journalists I'll find in the sample. I will conduct a logistical regression.

Can anybody help me with estimating if this is enough articles (power sample size)? I have tried the `powerlog` in Stata, but I can't account for the cluster-structure arising from having multiple articles from the same journalists.

Please do let me know if I should improve the questioning (as I'm new on this forum).

Comment: Welcome to CV! Some questions: (1) Why do you want to conduct a power estimation if you have a fixed sample size? (2) If you are using logistic regression, what is the outcome? If it is not *which journalist*, then the repeated journalists will cause some dependence in your data, which you could account for in a mixed model, but not ordinary logistic regression. If it is *which journalist*, then I could you explain how you intend to classify more than two labels using a binary classifier?

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear:
1) The reason for the power estimation is, that I want to evaluate the feasiblity of the project before conducting it.
2) The outcome is the presence/absence of a specific framing in each article. The independent variables are features of the journalist and the news paper etc. 

Do that clarify it? Otherwise, please let me know.